# listView does not refresh with new values

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I have a problem while refreshing the list view from old values to new values. 
Through a search for many hours i have got that **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**  has to be used. 
But i am unable to understand how do i use it as whenever i use it gives me an error

"The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter"

i am not sure whether i am doing the right thing. please Help...

This is my Code

```
public class Slider extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnDrawerOpenListener, OnDrawerCloseListener {

Button mCloseButton;
Button mOpenButton;
MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer mDrawer;
ListView list;
TextView t1;
String data, query, is;
Spinner d;
String FILENAME = "http://24.php";
ArrayList<String> pos;
ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;

HashMap<String, String> map;

static String j_id = null;
static Object j_make = null;
static String j_model = null;
static String j_version = null;
static String j_price = null;
static String j_reg_plc = null;

String ID = "car_id";
String MAKE = "make";
String MODEL = "model";
String VERSION = "version";
String PRICE = "expected_price";
String PLACE_REG = "registration_place";
CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5, cb6, cb7, cb8, cb9, cb10;
Spinner sp1;
int flag = 0;
String drive[] = new String[] { "Select Drive", "Two-Wheel Drive",
        "Four-Wheel Drive", "All-Wheel Drive" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.slider);

    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noRec);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    cb6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
    cb7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
    cb8 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);
    cb9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);
    cb10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox10);
    d = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.drive);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter spdrv = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, drive);
    d.setAdapter(spdrv);

    t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    pos = new ArrayList<String>();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String stuff = bundle.getString("stuff");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stuff= |" + stuff + "|",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (stuff.contains("null")) {

        t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        t1.setText("No Records Found");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Records Found!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        load_list(stuff);              //Load list with values

    }

    mCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = 1;
            query = "Select make, model, version, expected_price, registration_place FROM `used_cars` where registration_place ="
                    + "'" + j_reg_plc + "'";
            if (cb1.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND transmission ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb2.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND ac ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb3.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND car_lockk ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb4.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND sunroof ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb5.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND window ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb6.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND seats ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb7.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND stearing ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb8.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND player ='Yes'";
            }

            if (cb9.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND sound_system ='Yes'";
            }
            if (cb10.isChecked()) {
                query = query + " AND wheels ='Yes'";
            }
            query = query + ";";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "QUERY= " + query,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("QUERY= " + query);
            startDownload();

            mDrawer.animateClose();
        }
    });

    mOpenButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mDrawer.isOpened())
                mDrawer.animateOpen();

        }
    });

}

private void startDownload() {

    new AppTask().execute(FILENAME);
}

public class AppTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "res" + result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pos = new ArrayList<String>();

        mylist.clear();
        load_list(result);         //Refresh list with new values

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://animsinc.com/filter.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    5);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Qry", query));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return is;
    }

}

@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    mCloseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_close);
    mOpenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_open);
    mDrawer = (MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // demo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // demo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void load_list(String lt) {

    // list.setAdapter(null);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside load_list", 100).show();
    try {

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(lt.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Inside load_list----FOR", 100).show();
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            j_id = jObject.getString(ID);
            j_make = jObject.getString(MAKE);
            j_model = jObject.getString(MODEL);
            j_version = jObject.getString(VERSION);
            j_price = jObject.getString(PRICE);
            j_reg_plc = jObject.getString(PLACE_REG);

            data = j_make + "";
            map.put("make", data);

            data = j_model + "";
            map.put("model", data);

            data = j_version + "";
            map.put("version", data);

            data = j_price + "";
            map.put("price", data);

            data = j_reg_plc + "";
            map.put("place", data);

            mylist.add(map);
            pos.add(j_id);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String[] from = new String[] { "make", "model", "version", "price",
            "place" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text5, R.id.text3, R.id.text4,
            R.id.text2 };
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.text_adaptr, from,
            to);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "B4 list setAdapter", 100)
            .show();

    // mylist.notifyDataSetChanged();

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ---------------------------------

    int[] colors = { 0, 0xff00ffff, 0 }; // red for the example
    list.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
    list.setDividerHeight(4);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String data = pos.get(position) + "";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data: " + data,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Display_Car dc=new Display_Car();
            // dc.get_cid(data);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Slider.this, Buy_View.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            // Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("stuff", data);
            // Add the bundle to the intent
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
    // ---------------------------------
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can use the runOnUiThread method as follows. If you're not using a ListActivity, just adapt the code to get a reference to your ArrayAdapter.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

You have to remember `notifyDataSetChanged()` works only when the data inside the adapter has changed, and it rerenders the list. In your case you change the data externally, so you have to change the data inside the adapter.

In such cases, use something like

```
((ItemArrayAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged() instead of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleAdapter` is a `BaseAdapter`. Change

```
ListAdapter adapter;
```

to

```
BaseAdapter adapter;
```

or  `SimpleAdapter adapter;`